# Laravel 4 - Google Sign In

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, google-oauth

I am new in Laravel

I am testing Google Sign In with oauth-4-laravel by following the guide. I am managed to select my google account but after that it returned the URL like:

http://host.com/google/loginwithgoogle?code=4/SXVJ-Ou9xLt60kZ-OR68DxxxxxXFD.kqJwUtyEmhcfXE-sT2ZxxxxxxxxxxxxigI

How can I handle this route within my Route.php file? My current code on Route.php is:

```
Route::get('login', function()
{
return View::make('login');
});

Route::controller('google', 'GoogleController');
```

And my GoogleController.php code

```
public function postLoginwithgoogle(){

    // get data from input
    $code = Input::get( 'code' );

    // get google service
    $googleService = OAuth::consumer( 'Google' );

    // check if code is valid

    // if code is provided get user data and sign in
    if ( !empty( $code ) ) {

        // This was a callback request from google, get the token
        $token = $googleService->requestAccessToken( $code );

        // Send a request with it
        $result = json_decode( $googleService->request( 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo' ), true );

        $message = 'Your unique Google user id is: ' . $result['id'] . ' and your name is ' . $result['name'];
        echo $message. "<br/>";

        //Var_dump
        //display whole array().
        dd($result);

    }
    // if not ask for permission first
    else {
        // get googleService authorization
        $url = $googleService->getAuthorizationUri();

        // return to facebook login url
        return Redirect::to( (string)$url );
    }
}
```

I suspect is the 'post' and 'get' but how should I code it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No route is needed. Just redirect the user to the URL:

```
Redirect::to('<URL provided by Google>');
```

See details in the [documentation](https://github.com/artdarek/oauth-4-laravel#usage).

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to specif a route to POST [artdarek/oauth-4-laravel](https://github.com/artdarek/oauth-4-laravel) works with GET by adding the token after the ? in the url. So basicly you don't need any extra routes.

There are some problems with your route though.The example you posted here assumes that Google redirects an authenticated user back to the same url with a valid token. In your case I gather that that is http://host.com/google/loginwithgoogle, and you want to use http://host.com/google. For this to happen you need to edit the route as follow:

```
Route::controller('google', 'GoogleController@postLoginwithgoogle'); //I would remove the "post" part of the name since it is misleading
```

when you redirect to host.com/google now when someone wants to login with Google then is should work.